# What is wrong with the path I am using to link css file to html file in GitHub?

Tags: html, css, github, deployment, relative-path

Here is the link to my repo: https://github.com/kadrianoliver/mariesmagictouch. When I first uploaded the files from my computer this was the code in my index.html to link to styles.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

My css file, "styles.css" was in a folder titled "css", but GitHub doesn't allow you to upload a folder  you have to upload a file, so the css file could no longer use this pathway. So I researched here and found people were using this code to link a css file to html in Github:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
```

But the deployment still just shows html and this path did not work either. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use github the way you do. You whould use git to push your files to github.

You should commit your changes and push them to your repo from the terminal. This way all files get uploaded in a bundle with comments, so you can change between commits in  the future if needed. 
[Tutorial for pushing with git to github](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTphObvEH9w)

Comment: Your response is greatly appreciated, Henrik! Thank you. I am new to Git and GitHub and don’t understand the terminology yet but I am looking over the video now. I’m sure this will help and I will keep you posted.